# C# OleDb sql "UPDATE, WHERE" exception

Tags: c#, sql, oledb

So I have the following code :

```
public static void WriteToDatabase(string sql,string value,int Amount, string URL)
    {
int times = int.Parse(((dr)[dt.Columns[1]]).ToString()) + Amount;
                    sql = "UPDATE Words "+
                          " SET Amount = " + times + 
                          " WHERE Word = " + value + 
                          " AND Website = " + URL + ";";
myAdp = new OleDbDataAdapter();
myAdp.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand(sql, myConn);
                    myAdp.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Which supposed to update a value in a pre-made Microsoft Access 2007 file, 
and whenever I run the code they following OleDb exception occurs :

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll ,
Syntax error missing operator in query expression : 'Word = meta AND Website = http://www.twitch.tv/directory'."
"

So I've searched the web for common errors that could happen, and I couldn't find any, 
I'll be glad if someone can find the mistake in the sql.
Thanks.

Comment: You need single quotes around string literals: `... where word = 'MyWord' and ...`  ALSO: if this is for a web app, you should definitely used parameters (instead of a "raw insert"): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlphp/archive/2008/09/30/how-and-why-to-use-parameterized-queries.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely should be using parameterized queries for this.  That is the right way to pass values in.

Your problem is that your query is missing single quotes:

```
"UPDATE Words "+
                      " SET Amount = " + times + 
                      " WHERE Word = '" + value + "'" +
                      " AND Website = '" + URL + "'"
```

But let me re-emphasize that although this should work, you should fix the code so it uses parameters

Comment: @EliranZiv until you get a _value_ with  a single quote inside IE *O'Brian*. Listen to the advice and learn how to do a parameterized query.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Word field is a varchar, you have forgotten the necessary single quotes around the variable. " WHERE Word = '" + value + "'"